# How to Update DataTable Columns in Vue3

Tags: datatables, vuejs3

In Vue3, I want to update the columns in my DataTables object when I click a dedicated button. It seems like the columns object is not reactive, despite the ref() notation. How can I achieve this? The example below is based on the code found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatables-net-vue3-reactive-jret2v?file=src%2FApp.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

import DataTable from 'datatables.net-vue3';
import DataTablesLib from 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-select';

DataTable.use(DataTablesLib);

let counter = 0;
let dt;
const data = ref([]);
const table = ref();
var columns = ref([
  {
    data: 'a',
    title: 'First',
  },
  {
    data: 'b',
    title: 'Second',
  },
  {
    data: 'c',
    title: 'Third',
  },
]);

// Initial data
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  add();
}

// Get a DataTables API reference
onMounted(function () {
  dt = table.value.dt;
});

// Add new rows - note how the data object in Vue is changed and the DataTable will reflect
// those changes, rather than using the DataTables API to manipulate the rows.
function add() {
  data.value.push({
    a: 'A-' + counter,
    b: 'B-' + counter,
    c: 'C-' + counter,
  });

  counter += 1;
}

function addColumns() {
  columns.value.push({
    data: 'd',
    title: 'Fourth',
  });
  console.log(columns);
}

// For each selected row just add an indicator to show that it's data has been updated
function update() {
  dt.rows({ selected: true }).every(function () {
    let row = this.data();

    row.a += ' Updated';
    row.b += ' Updated';
    row.c += ' Updated';
  });
}

// For each selected row find the data object in `data` array and remove it
function remove() {
  dt.rows({ selected: true }).every(function () {
    let idx = data.value.indexOf(this.data());
    data.value.splice(idx, 1);
  });
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Simple table</h1>
    <h2>DataTables + Vue3 example</h2>
    <p>
      This example demonstrates the <code>datatables.net-vue3</code> package
      being used to display an interactive DataTable in a Vue application.
    </p>

    <button @click="add">Add new row</button><br />
    <button @click="addColumns">Add new column</button><br />
    <button @click="update">Update selected rows</button><br />
    <button @click="remove">Delete selected rows</button>

    <DataTable
      class="display"
      :columns="columns"
      :data="data"
      :options="{ select: true }"
      ref="table"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
@import 'datatables.net-dt';
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't looked at the source code but I'm guessing the columns are specially created during the DataTable initialization and can't be reactively updated. You'll need to unmount and remount the `<DataTable>` component when updating the columns. This can be done with the [key](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key) attribute. Whenever key changes, the component will remount so just tie key to `columns.length`

```html
<DataTable
  class="display"
  :columns="columns"
  :data="data"
  :options="{ select: true }"
  ref="table"
  :key="columns.length"
/>
```

As a side-effect, the DataTable will throw an error if the new column property is not found on the row `data`.  You will need to initialize this new row data at the same time.

```js
function addColumns() {
  data.value.forEach((d, index) => (d.d = 'D-' + index));
  columns.value.push({
    data: 'd',
    title: 'Fourth',
  });
}
```

Similarly, after adding a column, newly added rows will also be expected to have the new column property...

[Updated StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatables-net-vue3-reactive-xebkg9?file=src%2FApp.vue)